# Browser.wait doesn't wait by given milliseconds

Tags: selenium, protractor, mocha.js, chai

So I am having issue with browser.wait with using protractor, mocha and chai. Basically a simple script I have created is basically:

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
describe('Personal information', function () {
    var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;

    this.timeout(5000);

    it('test', function (done) {

        browser.driver
            .then(() => browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(element(by.xpath("//root"), 1000, "timed out TEST")
            .then(() => done());
    });
```

as you can see I have added a function `this.timeout(5000);` which means after 5 seconds it would throw a error however I have entered inside the browser.wait a timeout after 1000 milliseconds which means after 1 seconds it should throw a error of time out after 1 second.

However it seems like it doesn't do that but instead waits 5 seconds and throws  `Error: Timeout of 5000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.` and I am so confused of what I am doing incorrect here. So here I am!

How can I be able to make it wait for the amount I have given?

To GUY UPDATE 2:

```
describe('Personal information', function () {
    var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;

    this.timeout(0);

    browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(element(by.xpath("//root"))), 1000, "timed out TEST");
    });
```

Comment: which version of selenium are U using ?? Does it work when You add await before timeout ???

Comment: @SkorpEN `"selenium-webdriver": "^4.0.0-alpha.1", "protractor": "^5.4.2",` - Where do you mean I should put await? not sure where you meant

Comment: `this.timeout()` is your function? what is behind it?

Comment: @Guy It is a mocha function `https://mochajs.org/api/Mocha.Suite.html#timeout`

Comment: try adding await before this.timeout().
So line should look "await this.timeout();"

Comment: I am not able to do that @SkorpEN `SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function`

Comment: so add async before function ().

Comment: I am not sure on how to do that :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure how `this.timeout()` works, but I suspect it behaves like implicit wait. `element(by.xpath("//root"))` tries to locate the element for the defined 5 seconds, only after that failed `browser.wait` check if the 1 second timeout was acceded.

You can set `this.timeout(0);` before using `browser.wait`.

Comment: Hey guy! I thought also about it. I changed to `this.timeout(0)` and it seems to be stuck forever where it doesnt continue until the element is found. - So once again the browser.wait still doesn't seem to do anythinng

Comment: @Thrillofit86 What happens if you take `browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(element(by.xpath("//root"))), 1000, "timed out TEST");` outside `it`?

Comment: Alright so I did that right below a line of the this.timeout(0) and it seems like still it just waits forever. I have updated the question to show you how it looks

Comment: @Thrillofit86 Is it waiting on this line or on the `it`? You didn't remove it. Perheps you have abother `timeout` before the `describe`?

Comment: I added the browser.wait before it triggers the `it` function. I do need the `it` later on either way for automated testing but it should be fine to have the browser.wait before the actual `it` function, no?

Comment: @Thrillofit86 Yes, it should be fine, but try a very simple `describe` with `browser.wait` only to test if the problem is there.

Comment: Just tested and I have updated the question. The problem still remains where it waits forever until it finds the element... - even if the element is there it still doesn't do anything - it doesnt continue after that either

Comment: you sure that's milliseconds?  Usually webdriver's WebDriverWait defaults to seconds.